# Applying styling to external library component in AntDesign

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Currently I am using `react-phone-input-2` I have overridden some styling using class selectors.

My issue now is, How can I trigger a conditional styling so it behaves similar/same to a normal Antd Input component on error?

I have the following CodeSandbox below.

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Don't import `import "react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css"` and use your component like this. But in this case you won't see flag dropdown so you will need to define this style yourself, or just copy them from `react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css`

```
      <Form.Item
        label="Phone"
        name="mobile"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your mobile!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <PhoneInput inputClass="ant-input" specialLabel={false} />
      </Form.Item>
```

2. Use component as I described in an example above but also import "react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css" and will try to override styles that will be similar  as Antd